# Newer kernel is installed but not available to load via grub

Tags: fedora, kernel

I've installed fedora 24 and updated kernel.

```
$rpm -qa kernel

kernel-4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64
kernel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

So `kernel-4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64` is installed.

```
$uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

Current loaded kernel.

```
$ cd /boot
$ ll
total 90117
...
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  6277656 Jul 29 07:09 vmlinuz-0-rescue-60cb3109c1ea41d6806444bff16cc074
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  6277656 May 19 16:21 vmlinuz-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

But there is no file for 4.6.4 kernel.

How is it possible to add newer kernel by hand into grub?

Comment: By the way is it a BIOS or UEFI system?

Comment: @sjsam BIOS but there is option UEFI load (disabled now)

Answer (score 0):

It's high time that you do

**For BIOS**

```
cp /boot/grub2/grub.cfg /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.bak # Creating a backup of current
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

---

**For UEFI**

Under EFI, GRUB 2 looks for its configuration in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`

```
cp /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.bak
grub2-mkconfig /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

---

**Note**

if you get

```
grub2-mkconfig : command not found
```

that means, you haven't installed the packages that provide these tools (very rare though!), then you need to install them first

```
dnf install grub2-efi grub2-efi-modules shim
```

Comment: That doesn't help since there is no image for `4.6.4`..
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.5-..
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.5.5-..
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue..
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue..
done

Answer (score 0):

edit grub.conf file if you are using Redhat/ Centos

Copy and edit the old kernel parameter and replace 
old parameters and locations with newer one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a clean install of F24, using the default partition layout. On my system /dev/sda1 was created solely for grub that is not normally mounted. To find it I did:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

and within fdisk p to show the partitions. Next mounted that partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

looked for the file with:

```
find /mnt -name grub.cfg
```

and finally updated the grub.cfg file with:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /mnt/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

This process must be repeated every time the kernel is updated.

Does anyone have a better fix than this?  It works, but I don't understand why it is not done automatically.  Did I miss a setting somewhere?